# Com utilizar a o SUM no laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

MODEL CLIENTES

```
 public function titulo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Titulo');
    }
```

MODEL TITULO

```
   public function cliente()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Cliente');
        }
```

MIGRATION TITULOS

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('titulos', function (Blueprint $table) {

           // cadastro padrão
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('referencia');

            $table->integer('tipo_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('tipo_id')->references('id')->on('titulo_tipos');

            $table->integer('cliente_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('cliente_id')->references('id')->on('clientes');

            $table->integer('devedor_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('devedor_id')->references('id')->on('devedors');

            $table->integer('user_id');

            $table->date('vencimento_titulo')->nullable();
            $table->double('valor')->nullable();
            $table->string('status')->default('pendente');
            $table->timestamps();

            // fim cadastro padrão


        });
```

MEU CÓDIGO:

```
DB::table('titulos')
        ->join('clientes', 'titulos.cliente_id', '=', 'clientes.id')
        ->select('cliente_id', DB::raw('SUM(valor) as total'))
        ->groupBy('cliente_id')
        ->get();
```

Tenho duas tabelas relacionadas ( Cliente e Titulos ), gostaria de montar uma consulta por cliente com a soma de todos os títulos trazendo campos da tabela cliente, como faço no laravel essa agregação com o SUM?

Resultado desejado:

```
CLIENTE.NOME |CLIENTE.CNPJ         | SUM(TITULOS.VALOR)
cliente A    | 01.200.300/00001-28 | R$ 8000      
cliente B    | 01.200.300/00001-28 | R$ 15000
```

DENTRO DO BANCO FUNCIONA TRANQUILAMENTE:

```
SELECT 
clientes.id,
clientes.nome,
clientes.cnpj,
(SELECT SUM(titulos.valor) FROM titulos where titulos.cliente_id = clientes.id ) as total
from
clientes ;
```

Comment: Qual  é o  erro que está a obter?

Comment: Faz ao inverso pela tabela de titulos carregando os dados do cliente é muito mais simples

Comment: Se for só o sum que quer no final da consulta coloca ->count();

Comment: Caso deseja usar no select usa dessa forma ->select(\DB::raw("SUM(coluna) as soma"));

Answer (score 0):

Para retorno da soma de registro no final de cada consulta coloque ->coun() como mostra exemplo:

```
DB::table('titulos')
        ->join('clientes', 'titulos.cliente_id', '=', 'clientes.id')
        ->groupBy('cliente_id')
        ->get()->count();
```

Caso seja no select segue o exemplo:

```
DB::table('titulos')
        ->join('clientes', 'titulos.cliente_id', '=', 'clientes.id')
        ->select('cliente_id', \DB::raw("SUM(valor) as total"))
        ->groupBy('cliente_id')
        ->get();
```

Outra coisa que indico você fazer é usar Float no lugar do Double.